# Error while defining my Keras model: " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes' "

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, model, keras

I'm trying to build a keras model, the problem appeared after adding lines to perform zero-padding then merge 2 layers. The code is as follows:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras.activations import softmax
import keras.backend as K

query = Input(name='query', shape=(10,))
doc = Input(name='doc', shape=(100,))
embedding = Embedding(1125, 50, trainable=True)
q_embed = embedding(query)
d_embed = embedding(doc)
q_w = Dense(1, use_bias=False)(q_embed)
q_w = Lambda(lambda x: softmax(x, axis=1), output_shape=(10,))(q_w)
q_w_layer = Lambda(lambda x: K.repeat_elements(q_w, rep=50, axis=2))(q_w)
q_embed = Multiply()([q_w_layer, q_embed])
cross = Dot(axes=[2, 2], normalize=False)([q_embed, d_embed])
cross = Permute((2, 1))(cross)
contxt = Conv1D(30, 5, strides=5, activation='relu', name="conv")(cross)
contxt = BatchNormalization()(contxt)
contxt = Dropout(0.2)(contxt)
attention = Dense(1, use_bias=False)(contxt)
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)
contxt = Multiply()([contxt, attention])
important_context = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2)
contxt = important_context(contxt)
word_level = Permute((2, 1))(cross)

# ############ This is the part that caused the problem

word_level_padd = K.reshape(ZeroPadding1D((0, contxt.shape[2] - word_level.shape[2]))(K.reshape(word_level,
                                (-1, 
                                 word_level.shape[2], 
                                 word_level.shape[1]
                                ))),
                           (-1, word_level.shape[1], contxt.shape[2])
                           ) if word_level.shape[-1] < contxt.shape[-1] else word_level
contxt_padded = K.reshape(ZeroPadding1D((0, word_level.shape[2] -contxt.shape[2]))(K.reshape(contxt,
                            (-1, 
                             contxt.shape[2], 
                             contxt.shape[1]
                           ))), 
                         (-1, contxt.shape[1], word_level.shape[2])
                         ) if contxt.shape[-1] < word_level.shape[-1] else contxt
contxt = Concatenate(axis=1, name="merge_levels")([word_level_padd, contxt_padded])

# This is the part that caused the problem #############

lstm_units = int(contxt.shape[1])
contxt = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=False))(contxt)
contxt = BatchNormalization()(contxt)
contxt = Dropout(0.2)(contxt)
out_ = Dense(1)(contxt)
model = Model(inputs=[query, doc], outputs=out_)
```

Here is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2910, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       model = Model(inputs=[query, doc], outputs=contxt)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line
>   93, in **init**
>       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line
>   237, in _init_graph_network
>       self.inputs, self.outputs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line
>   1353, in _map_graph_network
>       tensor_index=tensor_index)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line
>   1340, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line
>   1340, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line
>   1340, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line
>   1340, in build_map
>       node_index, tensor_index)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line
>   1312, in build_map
>       node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Comment: Where in your code are `query` and `doc` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I've just added the missing declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure because of the if-conditions, but this might help:

The input and output layers that you pass when declaring a Keras `model` should be connected to each other by means of `Layer` objects. This is not the case in your code: the `K.reshape` operation that you assign to `word_level_padd` and `contxt_padded` are no `Layer` instances.

You can solve this by wrapping the reshape operation in a `Lambda` layer:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
contxt_padded = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(x))(...)
```

A `Lambda` layers allows to wrap arbitrary functions that operate on tensors in a `Layer` instance to include them in your model.

Comment: It works. I modified the `Reshape` layers following your example, like this: `word_level_padd = Lambda(lambda x: K.reshape(ZeroPadding1D((0, contxt.shape[2] -x.shape[2]))(K.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[2], x.shape[1]))), (-1, x.shape[1], contxt.shape[2])) if x.shape[-1] < contxt.shape[-1] else x)(word_level)`